# Mobile Backend as a Service for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-phone-8

I want to implement Mobile Backend as a Serivce (MBaaS) for a Windows Phone 8 application.
Could someone let me know which is the best service provider for same. All I have came across so far is www.parse.com. Would like to explore other options too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) would fit the bill - storage, back end tasks, push notifications, with support for other platforms like Windows 8, iOS and Android.  You can get a [free account here](http://aka.ms/GetAzureTrial).

SkyDrive is a great choice for personal cloud storage associated with your application, but that's IMO just a small subset of BaaS.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't SkyDrive the obvious choice? Perhaps you could elaborate more on what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Antonio Martinez [compared some alternatives](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) a while back, including

- [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)
- [StackMob](https://stackmob.com/)
- [Accelerator Cloud Service](http://www.appcelerator.com/cloud/)
- [Applicasa](http://www.applicasa.com/)
- [Kinvey](http://www.kinvey.com/)

The site is focused on iOS development, and I guess that's why he doesn't include Azure.